# Image doesn't display in the screen while using Flatlist and Give error 'value for uri cannot be cast from Double to String'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I tried to display image in the flastlist but images doesn't display and give the error "Error while updating property 'src' of a view managed by : RTCImageView.

What is wrong with my code? I wanted to fetch the images from arrays which is in the state form.

```
  this.state = {
        DATA : [
        {
          image: require ('../assets/a.jpg'),
          address: 'Gaichaur',
          date: Date.now(),
          interval: '7:00 PM - 11:00 PM',
        },
        {
          image:  require ('../assets/a.jpg'),
          address: 'Gaichaur',
          date: Date.now(),
          interval: '7:00 PM - 11:00 PM',
        },
        {
          image: require ('../assets/a.jpg') ,
          address: 'Gaichaur',
          date: Date.now(),
          interval: '7:00 PM - 11:00 PM',
        },
        {
          image: require ('../assets/a.jpg') ,
          address: 'Gaichaur',
          date: Date.now(),
          interval: '7:00 PM - 11:00 PM',
        },
      ]};
  }

  _renderData = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Image  source={ {uri : item.image} } style={styles.imageView}  />
        <View style={styles.cardText}>
          <Text>{item.address}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text1}>hello</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{new  Date(item.date).toDateString()}</Text>
        <Text>{item.interval}</Text>
      </Card>
    );

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this syntax:

`<Image  source={item.image} style={styles.imageView}  />`